# Can ping RPi 3 but not SSH or http

Tags: networking, ssh, ping

I have an RPi 3 with OpenMediaVault installed, running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). It has an ethernet connection to a DLink switch, which in turn has an ethernet connection to i) my Win7 Pro(64bit) SP1 laptop, and ii) a TPLink WiFi repeater. The repeater has a WiFi connection to a TPLink router (192.168.1.1), which is acting as the DHCP server for the network. The Pi is acting as server for RAID disk array, but it has a static IP address (192.168.1.120)

Until yesterday, this setup has been working correctly for several months. Today the Pi is no longer accessible over the network. I have tried rebooting the Pi several times, as well as the router and repeater. I have changed nothing in the Pi's configuration. I can ping it from the Win7 laptop, but the normal http interface is unable to connect. PuTTY, which used to work, now states 'Connection refused' (SSH on port 22).

Logging into the Pi I can successfully ping my laptop and the router. Ifconfig gives:

```
eth0   Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8.....
       inet addr:192.168.1.120 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
       RX packets:31461 errors:0 dropped:33 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:452 srrors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
       RX bytes:2222151 (2.1 MiB) TX bytes:36019 (35.1 KiB)

lo     Link encap:Local Loopback
       inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
       RX packets:67 errors:0 dropeed:0 overruns:0 frame:0
       TX packets:67 errors:0 dropeed:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
       RX bytes:5088 (4.9 KiB) TX bytes:5088 (4.9 KiB)
```

Any help to get it accessible on the network again would be much appreciated (all my work is on it!)

Comment: Can you run `netstat -l` on the pi? This way you check whether it's still listening on the ssh (22) and http (80) ports. Also to check ssh you can try logging in to localhost on the pi `ssh localhost`. You should be able to log on to the pi if ssh is running ok.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at /var/log/syslog revealed that one of the (three) attached HDD disks had exceeded its memory allocation (What does that mean?). When I unplugged that particular disk and rebooted the RPi, 192.168.1.120 became visible and responsive again. I now have full access to the RPi via http and SSH. I have no idea why this happened. I have since plugged the disk back in and the system is still working. For now.